# Expected expression in __unsafe_unretained

Tags: objective-c

The line of code is:

```
drawShapes (__unsafe_unretained shapes, 3);
```

The error that pops up is "Expected expression". Exactly where am i missing an expression? I tried putting * and extra pair of parenthesis but it didn't work?
May someone help me?
thanks

Comment: Could you please post more code statements? What is the function declaration of drawShapes? and what is the type of shapes?

Comment: Agreed. More code needed. Also, I would highly discourage using __unsafe_unretained. Its rarely needed

Comment: What is the use of `__unsafe_unretained` in this case any way?

Answer (score 0):

`__unsafe_unretained` is an *ownership qualifier* which is used in a declaration. In your code:

```
drawShapes (__unsafe_unretained shapes, 3);
```

you have used it as a prefix to the expression `shapes` in the first argument to the call. The compiler is looking for an expression and  finds an ownership qualifier, so it reports "Expected expression".

I can only guess what your intention might be, but if you want your function `drawShapes` to not hold a strong reference to its passed argument you can declare it as something like:

```
void drawShapes(__unsafe_unretained NSObject *obj, int x) { ... }
```

but be **very sure** you know what you are doing!

HTH